# Pell-Fermat equation

Tags: number-theory

I was reading Pell-Fermat equation from Arthur Engel's book Problem Solving Strategies. The equation is $x^2-dy^2=1$, where $ d$ is not a square. It says about finding all the solutions of this equation. Can anyone explain it?I mean  I am not getting the complete solution about what they are trying to do? I don't get it how we are considering $x_0+y_0\sqrt{d}$  a solution for the above equation if $(x_0,y_0)$ is  a solution.Also the portion where it says,"we could  have integrated its square factors",I am not sure what they are trying to mean .... Well, the method demonstrated as follows:

> We may assume that d is also square free. If it were not square free we could have integrated its square factors. We associate each number $x+y\sqrt{d}$ with every integer $(x,y)$.
> We have the factorization $x^2-dy^2=(x+y\sqrt{d})(x-y\sqrt{d})$. It follows from  here the product and quotient of two solutions of the equation is again a solution of this equation. If $x,y>0$ ,then it follows from $x^2-dy^2=1$ that $(x+y\sqrt{d})$ and $(x-y\sqrt{d})$ are positive. In addition the first one is >1 and the second<1. We consider the smallest solutions $x_{0}+y_{0}\sqrt{d}$. Then we will show that all the solutions given by $(x_0+y_0\sqrt{d})^n$, $n\in\mathbb{Z}$. We will prove this by the ingenious method of descent.  Suppose there is another solution $u+v\sqrt{d}$ which is not a power of $x_0+y_0\sqrt{d}$. Then it must lie between two succeeding powers of $x_0+y_0\sqrt{d}$ that is for some $n$,
> $(x_0+y_0\sqrt{d})<u+v\sqrt{d}<(x_0+y_0\sqrt{d})^{n+1}$.
> Multiplying with the solution $x_0-y_0\sqrt{d}$, we get
> $$1<(u-v\sqrt{d}(x_0+y_0\sqrt{d})^n<(x_0+y_0\sqrt{d})$$
> The middle term of the inequality chain is a solution and because it is larger than 1, it is a positive solution. This is a contradiction because we have found a positive solution which is smaller than the smallest positive solution. Thus every solution is a power of the smallest positive solution.

Answer (score 1):

We are simply associating the number $x + y\sqrt d$ to every solution $(x,y)$, then by "abuse of notation" we consider $x + y\sqrt d$ to be the solution itself, instead of $(x,y)$.

No information is lost, and when they say "consider the solution $x_0 + y_0 \sqrt d$" that is abuse of notation for "consider the solution $(x_0, y_0)$".

But the advantage of using a real number $x + y \sqrt d$ is that you can now order these solutions, which is the essential part of the quoted text, whose result is that every solution (as a real number) is $\pm$ of a power of the smallest positive solution (as a real number).

---

When they say "integrate the square factors", they mean "integrate the square factors into the equation", i.e. if you want to solve $x^2 - 12 y^2 = 1$, where $12 = 2^2 \times 3$, you can rewrite this as $x^2 - 3 (2y)^2 = 1$, where the square factor $2$ is now part of the variable $2y$, and you can make the variable change $z=2y$ to make the equation becomes $x^2 - 3z^2 = 1$, which will include more solutions (since $z$ doesn't need to be even).

Comment: Thank you for the solution...but can you please specify how is the product and quotient of two solutions $x_0+y_0\sqrt{d}$ is a solution in itself ....I am just not getting the idea behind it....

Comment: Call $x_0 - y_0 \sqrt d$ the conjugate of $x_0 + y_0 \sqrt d$, notated $\overline{x_0 + y_0 \sqrt d}$. Then this conjugation commutes with product and quotient, so if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are solutions of $z \overline{z} = 1$, then $(\alpha \beta) (\overline{\alpha \beta}) = 1$.

Comment: The key point (which the author failed to specify) is that we are now working in the ring $\Bbb Z[\sqrt d]$ with the norm function $x + y \sqrt d \mapsto x^2 - d y^2$ and the conjugation function $x + y \sqrt d \mapsto x - y \sqrt d$.

Comment: thank's a lot for that...but just one last thing about when they associate $x+y\sqrt{d}$ with the solution $(x,y)$ and finally draws up the conclusion that all the solutions are of the form $(x+y\sqrt{d})^n$ (where $(x,y)$ are solutions of the equation) what does that imply if we want to revert back to our original notation $(x,y)^n$( are the solutions of the equation)....this does not make any sense ....what does that mean.....

Comment: You need to compute $(x+y \sqrt d)^n$ and then express it as something $+$ something $\sqrt d$, e.g. $(3 + 2 \sqrt 2)^2 = 17 + 12 \sqrt 2$, so $(3,2)$ gives $(17,12)$ when $d=2$.